# Setting BTC Pay Server invoice expiration time to never?

Tags: btcpay-server

This is a follow up question to [this post](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/96568/using-btcpay-to-accept-undefined-payment-amounts) but my question is more programming related so I'm hoping this is the right place to post it.

I too  am trying to use BTC Pay Server as a wallet. Thera are two problems:

1. As described in the article, you have to specify an amount when creating an invoice.
2. [It has a security feature that basically results in you not being able to re-use deposit addresses](https://docs.btcpayserver.org/FAQ/FAQ-General/#how-does-btcpay-create-a-new-address-for-each-invoice).

The workaround for problem 1 is to set the invoice amount to 0.000001 BTC. So low that the client will always overpay. That works for me to.

But my problem is that address must not expire ever. I checked the code:

1. [Here](https://github.com/btcpayserver/btcpayserver-php-client/blob/master/src/BTCPayServer/Invoice.php) you can see the Invoice object.
2. [Here](https://github.com/btcpayserver/btcpayserver-php-client/blob/master/examples/tutorial/003_createInvoice.php) you can see the code in use.

It looks like I might be able to use this:

```
public function setExpirationTime($expirationTime)
{
    if (is_a($expirationTime, 'DateTime')) {
        $this->expirationTime = $expirationTime;
    } else if (is_numeric($expirationTime)) {
        $expirationDateTime = new \DateTime('', new \DateTimeZone("UTC"));
        $expirationDateTime->setTimestamp($expirationTime);
        $this->expirationTime = $expirationDateTime;
    }
    return $this;
}
```

And set the expiration time to the year 3000. So my questions are:

1. Will BTC Pay server ditch my address if I attempt to use this to make it never expire?
2. Will I still receive the funds if a user sends to an expired address/
3. Or is there perhaps a better way to get BTC Pay server to act as a wallet as I want it to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Will BTC Pay server ditch my address if I attempt to use this to
>    make it never expire?

Actually, you may encounter the [year 2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) if the type for expirationTime is DateTime. If that really is the case, it will be set a negative value when you try to pass a value larger than 2038. It is unclear what will happen next.

If the system the code is running on is 64bit, then the Y2038 problem does not apply.

> 2. Will I still receive the funds if a user sends
>    to an expired address

https://docs.btcpayserver.org/FAQ/FAQ-Stores/#payment-invalid-if-transactions-fails-to-confirm-minutes-after-invoice-expiration

> If the customer pays the invoice, but it fails to get the defined
> number of confirmations within the set period, it is marked as
> "invalid." The merchant can then decide whether to accept the invoice
> afterward manually or decline it and require additional payment from
> the customer. This is an additional protection mechanism against the
> volatility

So not exactly - some work is required on your part to accept it, if it expires.

> 3. Or is there perhaps a better way to get BTC
>    Pay server to act as a wallet as I want it to?

Instead of setting it to the year 3000, why don't you just set the invoice a year ahead at a time ?

Comment: It seems you can still deposit to the address even after it has expired. Which is great!

Comment: @coderama yes, it’s up to you to decide whether to accept it or not.